# Step functions on $[a,b]$ are dense in $\mathcal C^0([a,b])$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $\|f \|=\sup_{[a,b]}|f|$. We consider ($\mathcal C^0([a,b]),\|\cdot \|)$ and $(\mathcal E([a,b]),\|\cdot \|)$ where $\mathcal E([a,b])$ is a set of the step functions on $[a,b]$. I have to show that $\mathcal E([a,b])$ is dense in $\mathcal C^0([a,b])$.

**There is my proof:**

Let $f\in\mathcal C^0([a,b])$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ it's also uniformly continuous and thus, there is a $\delta>0$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x,y\in[a,b]$ s.t. $|x-y|<\delta$. Let $a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b$ such that $x_{i+1}-x_i<\delta$ for all $i$. We set $\varphi(x)=f(x_i)$ for all $i=0,...,n-1$ and $\varphi(x_n)=f(x_n)$. Therefore, if $x\in[a,b[$, there is a $i$ such that $x_i\leq x<x_{i+1}$ and thus $$|f(x)-\varphi(x)|=|f(x)-\varphi(x_i)|<\varepsilon$$ since $|x-x_i|<\delta$. Finally, since $f(b)=\varphi(b)$ we get that 
$$\forall x\in[a,b], |f(x)-\varphi(x)|<\varepsilon$$
and thus $$\|f-\varphi\|=\sup_{[a,b]}|f-\varphi|<\varepsilon$$
what prove the claim.

**Q1) Is it correct ?**

**Q2) Something is strange to me. If $A$ is dense in $B$, in particular $A\subset B$, but here, how can $\mathcal E([a,b])\subset \mathcal C^0([a,b])$ since an element of $\mathcal E([a,b])$ is not necessarily continuous ?**

Comment: That looks great. Maybe I would just have say at the beginning --> as $f$ is continuous and $[a,b]$ compact, $ f$ is uniform continuous according to the Hein-Cantor theorem.

Comment: What are step functions and $C^0$ to you? Your terminology and notation are a bit nonstandard.

Comment: Guess why it is denoted $\mathcal{E}$

Answer (score 5):

You're right about the thing you say looks strange. It's simply not correct to say the step functions are dense in the continuous functions, because they're not a subset of the continuous functions.

Comment: Ok thanks, so how do you call such a result ? (because in my course it's written "show that $\mathcal E([a,b])$ is dense in $\mathcal C^0([a,b])$). Actually, it look to be similar to say that $\mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb Q$ which has also no sense.

Comment: I doubt that there's a single word for this.

Comment: @idm : You could say that every continuous function on $[a,b]$ can be uniformly approximated by step functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Uniform continuity means that you can use a finite number of balls to cover the domain, and in each of those balls, the values of the functions are $\varepsilon$-close. Hence, you can build a step function that is $\varepsilon$-close to the given function.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question 2, $\mathcal C^0([a,b])$ is a subspace of the vectorial space $\mathcal F([a,b])$ of the real function defined on $[a,b]$. $\mathcal E([a,b])$ is also a subspace of $\mathcal F([a,b])$.

This is why you can say that $\mathcal E([a,b])$ is dense in $\mathcal C^0([a,b])$.

However, you're right, the formal definition of density is defined for subspaces.

Comment: ok, I see, is like to say that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q$, right ?

Comment: ??? You say we can say this is dense in that although the definition says this makes no sense? A person _could_ say that this is contained in the closure of that...

Comment: @David If you define $A$ is dense in $B$ iff $B \subseteq \bar{A}$, you should be fine.

Comment: @FelixB. It would also work if we defined A dense in B to mean 2 + 2 = 4. (Q: How many legs does a dog have if you call the tail a leg? A: 4.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich 
1. Does it extend the definition in an intuitive manner?
2. Does it break things?
3. Is there another possible extension you could confuse it with?
No? Well then there is no reason to not assume that definition. And more than half of all mathematics tries to find extensions/generalizations to existing stuff.

Comment: @FelixB. A "possible" reason not to assume that definition is that it's  going to case confusion for no reason. To put it another way, jorldle hurdy kwet. (Makes perfect sense if you assume appropriate definitions).

Answer (score 1):

Are the irrationals dense in the rationals? That doesn't sound right to me.

But we can let $X$ be the vector space of bounded real (or complex) functions on $[0,1]$ with norm $\|f\| = \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|.$ That makes $X$ into a Bananch space. In this giant metric space $X$ it makes sense to say $\overline {\mathcal E([a,b])}$ contains $C([a,b]).$

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is rather that the simple functions are dense in the measurable functions with pointwise topology (by definition). For bounded measurable functions this amounts even to the uniform topology, i.e. given a bounded measurable function one can find a sequence of simple functions that converge uniformly to the function.

Now continuous functions are measurable and on a compact bounded.

There may be some subtlties about null sets however depending on the precise definition of measurable I suppose.